# Time complexity of generating all possible permutations using backtracking (comparison of 2 solutions)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, permutation, backtracking, n-queens

**Approach 1 :**

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/ Here, we can see the recurrence equation to be T(N) = N * T(N-1) + c so the final time complexity comes out to be = O(N!), which makes sense.

**Approach 2 :**

[image]

The difference between this code and approach 1 is that we're doing some wasteful work everytime (when chosen[i] is true, we continue instead of moving down the recursion tree).
I think, the recurrence relation here should be T(N) = N * T(N-1) + N * c as we can divide the for loop into 2 parts : one where we do constant work in each iteration (N * c) and one where we make recursive calls (N * T(N-1)). Then for T(N-1) = (N-1) * T(N-2) + N*c (note that we're still paying N * c cost here) and so on. At the end, we'll have a term of N^N left and that will dominate O(N!) for large N. So does this mean that the time complexity of 2nd code snippet is O(N^N) and not O(N!)?

**Relation question :**
For N queens problem, we have a backtracking solution (can refer https://dev.to/chengmuy/optimizing-an-n-queens-solution-3m1m) but here, we have a for loop which checks whether or not the current state is safe (in O(1) average time) and makes recursive calls accordingly. Unless I'm wrong, the time complexity of this backtracking solution is also O(N!). But, I'm confused how we factor in the cost of early terminated branches in O(N!) i.e. basically the cost of having to check all the rows for current column (or columns for current row, depending on implementation) which are safe every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both algorithms, the recursive function is entered once for every prefix of a permutation of `{1, …, n}`. In the first algorithm, we can imagine the work done by each iteration of the `for` loop being accounted for inside the recursive call, since there will be a recursive call for every iteration. So the total amount of work is proportional to the number of possible prefixes. Since they are not proper prefixes, this includes all the permutations; so there are more than n! prefixes in all. In fact, the number of prefixes of length n-1 is also n!, so there are more than 2(n!) prefixes, but the remaining terms drop off pretty rapidly. It turns out that there are asymptotically *e*(n!) prefixes, where *e* is Euler's constant, approximately 2.71828. So that's O(n!), since we can ignore constant factors.

Now what about the second algorithm? We have the same number of recursive calls but each recursive call which does not correspond to a complete permutation requires a scan over the `chosen` array, which has n elements. That adds n × (*e* - 1) × n!. In effect, it changes the asymptote to O((n+1)!), which is bigger than O(n!). But not as much as O(n<sup>n</sup>).

Comment: Interesting. Do you have a source on there being asymptotically eN! possible prefixes over the N! permutations? I can see that it's correct, I just don't see why. And it would prove that this is an optimal algorithm.

Comment: @inordirection: The number of k-prefixes of all permutations of n objects is n!/(n-k)!, so the total number of prefixes of any size is n! times the sum of the inverse factorials from 0 to n. And it's pretty well known that the limit of the sum of inverse factorials is *e*, no? Iirc you can prove it from the Taylor expansion of exp(x).

Comment: Prefix-counting has been pretty handy for me, although it doesn't seem to be widely used. Or perhaps it's just that I haven't got much formal education in algorithm analysis; maybe it actually is common. People who know more math than me seem to have lots of other useful tools but this one has served my needs pretty well :-) anyway, I don't have a citation. Sorry. (And Heap's algorithm does half as many swaps. It's not asymptotically faster but it's generally considered faster.)

Comment: Yep, that makes perfect sense, thank you! Summing across all k-prefixes does make it pretty straightforward, but the hard part is thinking to do that!

Comment: I was actually stuck on pretty much this exact problem a couple weeks ago (counting prefixes, but of n C k rather than n!), and I think this will help.